# Showing Off Our Total Number of Likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

When I look at my 'Insights' page I see that we had a total of 1k+ likes. Yet on my home page like button it only shows 200+. Is there a way to capture the total number of likes across the domain and show this off on my website home page?

(We have lots of products with individual like buttons)

I've searched on stackoverflow and on the API documentation but cannot see a way to do this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not without periodically checking the graph API for the like buttons you know the URLs of and adding them togethers.
If you decide to do this i recommend caching the answer for a while so as not to hit rate limits on the Facebook API side or have issues with your page loading being delayed waiting for a response from the API